# Not able to Upgrade or Install any update or some packages aswell

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, troubleshooting, dpkg

Hey I encountered this error while upgrading. I don't know where did I messed it up.

Whenever I try to upgrade or install or even try to configure dpkg I get this error.

I am facing this issue **since 2 weeks** after searching alot on StackExchange and UbuntuForum I am posting this question here.

Please help

I am Currently on **Ubuntu 18.04.03 LTS**

```
divyang@divyang:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.15.0-55 linux-headers-4.15.0-55-generic
  linux-headers-4.18.0-15 linux-headers-4.18.0-15-generic
  linux-image-4.15.0-55-generic linux-image-4.18.0-15-generic
  linux-modules-4.15.0-55-generic linux-modules-4.18.0-15-generic
  linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-55-generic linux-modules-extra-4.18.0-15-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/321 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
dpkg: error processing package gvfs-backends (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
Errors were encountered while processing:
 gvfs-backends
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

```
divyang@divyang:~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
dpkg: error processing package gvfs-backends (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
Errors were encountered while processing:
 gvfs-backends
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You should try uninstall package first and then try to install it again.

```
sudo apt remove --purge gvfs-backends; sudo apt install gvfs-backends
```

and then do the upgrade:

```
sudo apt upgrade
```